# converting string"xy" into "x" and "y"

Tags: vb.net

I have seen lots of example on how to split a string in vb but I haven't been able to get them to work for me.

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a seat  number which is "`A1`" and i want to have have 2 variables which will be "`A`" and then "`1`".(I'm also going to be making the A into a value of one so if you also know the ASCII conversion for it it would be very helpful, but keep in mind I also want "`B`" to be 2 and so on).

```
If currentShowingID = BookingDetails(y).ShowingID Then
     tempSeat = BookingDetails(y).SeatNO
     Dim seat As String() = Split(tempSeat, "")
     Dim down As String = seat(0)
     Dim across As Integer = seat(1)
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't you tag the question with `vb.net` then? Why the `visual-studio` tag?

Comment: I'm guessing you could have values such as `"D13"` (or even `"AC13"` if it's a very large theater)... perhaps a regular expression is a better approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASCII table has codes for every character that it can represent, so...

- A => 65
- B => 66
- C => 67
- ...
- Z => 90

... which means that if you want to get a number to represent each character, starting at 1, you have to subtract 64 from the ASCII code of that character. The code below should work fine for you, assuming that your seats will always have two characters (ex.: A1, C5 D9)...

```
    Dim location As String
    location = "B1"

    Dim row As Char
    Dim rowId As Int32
    Dim number As Char

    row = location.Chars(0)
    rowId = Asc(row) - 64
    number = location.Chars(1)

    Console.WriteLine($"Location: {location} | Row: {row}({rowId}) | Number: {number} |")
    Console.ReadKey()
```

... in the other hand, if you will have letters from A-Z and numbers that can be greater than 9 (ex.: A20, K15), I would recommend you to take another path, such as...

```
    Dim number As Int32

    [...]

    row = location.Chars(0)
    rowId = Asc(row) - 64

    number = 0
    Int32.TryParse(location.Substring(1), number)
```

... test it and let us know!

Comment: To clarify yes the the numbers can go higher than 9 and when i'm using your suggestion there is an error because variable number can not be assigned an integer value of 0.

Comment: I've changed some parts of your answer but i have got it working , need to do some more testing and make it work for the other screens in the theater.Thanks !!

Comment: Glad that I've managed to help you! I forgot to tell you to change the type of the variable number, my bad, I saw that on my code and changed it later! (edited)